# when i want delete to to-do-list from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

when i want delete to to-do-list from `localStorage`
i can delete from UI but i can't delete from `localStorage`

```
function deleteTodoFromStorage(deletetodo){
  let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

  todos.forEach(function(todo,index){
    console.log(todo,deletetodo,index)
    if (todo === deletetodo){
        todos.splice(index,1);
        console.log("Test");
    } 
  });

  localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos));
}
```

Comment: You may need to better specify your function so we can help

Comment: http://notes.io/6jTs full code here (my own code) and original code here: http://notes.io/6jTd @Jalu

Comment: How would we know if your references are incorrect or that your layout is so invalid tags are not being recognized? Post some Html in a  [mcve]

Comment: use localStorage.removeItem('todos');

Answer (score 1):

You should not call forEach on todos and splice itself inside callbacks (which may causes index changing). I suggest you to use filter method instead.

```
newTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo !== deletetodo) 
localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(newTodos))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
function deleteTodoFromStorage(todoToRemove) {
localStorage.setItem(
    "todos",
    JSON.stringify(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")).filter(todoItem => {
            return todoItem !== todoToRemove;
        })
    )
);
}

deleteTodoFromStorage("buy milk"); // or anything else
```